# Kivy: ScreenManager - Accessing child properties

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am building an app and I need it to repeatedly count down to zero until the time limit is reached. This all works fine, but my current problem is that when it ends I want one of the labels to say "Finished" and having attempted to use the ids method, I always receive a KeyError: 'count_down1' message as the app crashes right at the end upon calling the finish_callback() function.

I am new to kivy, but my best guess is that self.ids[] refers to an id defined in the root widget (i.e. WindowManager), but the id: 'count_down1' is in one of WindowManager's child widgets (i.e. SecondWindow). However, even if this is correct I have been unable to work out how to rectify this and haven't had any success with extracting the correct answer from other similar questions.

#### py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from random import randint


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    a = NumericProperty(0)
    b = NumericProperty(0)
    run_t = 5
    min = 3
    max = 7

    def reset(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 0

    def start(self, *args):
        self.a = randint(self.min, self.max)
        self.anim = Animation(a = 0, duration = self.a)
        if self.run_t - self.b <= self.max:
            self.a = self.run_t - self.b
            print("a=", self.a, "b=", self.b)
            self.anim = Animation(a = 0, duration = self.a)
        else:
            print(self.run_t - self.b)
            self.anim.bind(on_complete = self.start)
    
        self.anim.start(self)

    def count_up(self):
        self.anim = Animation(b = self.run_t, duration = self.run_t)
        self.anim.bind(on_complete = self.finish_callback)
        self.anim.start(self)

    def finish_callback(self, animation, param):
        print('in finish_callback')
        end_1 = self.ids['count_down1']
        end_1.text = 'Finished'
        #^^this is where the error occurs^^


 kv = Builder.load_file("updown.kv")

class PageScrollerApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PageScrollerApp().run()
```

#### kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "home"

    FloatLayout:        
        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "y":0.05}
            text: "Go!"
            on_release:
                root.manager.reset()
                root.manager.start()
                root.manager.count_up()
                root.manager.current = 'low'

<SecondWindow>:
    name: 'low'

    FloatLayout:        
        Label:            
            id: count_down1
            text: str(round(root.manager.a, 1))
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "y": 0.55}
        Label:           
            id: count_up1
            text: str(round(root.manager.b, 1))
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "y": 0.3}
        Button:
            background_color: 0.5,0.1,1,1
            text: 'Cancel'
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "y":0.05}
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "medium"

<TextInput>
    size_hint: 0.24,0.1
    font_size: 35

<Button>
    font_size: 20
    color:1,0.2,0.5,1
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
    background_color: 0.5,0.8,0.2,1

<Label>
    font_size: 20
    color:1,0.2,0.5,1
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
    background_color: 0.5,0.2,0.9,1
```

I have tried to remove all of the unnecessary code for readability purposes. In summary, I think my question is how do I access and alter properties of a child widget? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem - KeyError

> receive a KeyError: 'count_down1' message as the app crashes right at
>   the end upon calling the finish_callback() function.

### Root Cause

The `id: count_down1` is not defined in the ScreenManager. It is defined in `SecondWindow()` but the ScreenManager has no access to it.

[Kv language » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets)

An `id` is limited in scope to the rule it is declared in, so in your app `count_down1` can not be accessed outside the `<SecondWindow>` rule.

### Solution

1. Add `id: second_window` to instantiated object, `SecondWindow:` so that you can reference any ids declared in `SecondWindow`
2. Replace `self.ids[`count_down1`]` with `self.ids.second_window.ids.count_down1`

#### Snippets - kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
        id: second_window
```

#### Snippets - py file

```
def finish_callback(self, animation, param):
    print('in finish_callback')
    self.ids.second_window.ids.count_down1.text = 'Finished'
```

Comment: Thank you. You are most welcome. You might want to check out [Kv language » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#referencing-widgets).